# Как отсортировать информацию в файле?

Tags: c++

Определить средний балл по университету и вывести список абитуриентов, средний балл которых выше среднего балла по университету в порядке убывания балла. Ключ: средний балл

```
struct StatementApplicants
{
    std::string fullName;
    int physics;
    int maths;
    int RussianLanguage;
    int English;
} applicants[256];


int main()
{
    std::string path = "SomeText.txt";
    fstream fStream;
    fStream.open(path, fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);
    if (!fStream.is_open())
        cout << "Error opening file!" << endl;
    else
    {
        int count;

        float averageMark;
        float studentAverageMark;
        float avg = 0;

        cout << "File opened successfully!\n" << endl;
        cout << "Add entries to file - click one" << endl;
        cout << "View records in a file - click two" << endl;
        cin >> count;


        if (count == 1)
        {
            cout << "\nNumber of applicants: ";
            int numberApplicants;
            cin >> numberApplicants;
            cout << "Enter information about " << numberApplicants << " applicants" << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < numberApplicants; i++)
            {
                cin.ignore();
                cout << "\nEnter full name: ";
                getline(cin, applicants[i].fullName);
                fStream << applicants[i].fullName << endl;

                cout << "Enter physics grade: ";
                cin >> applicants[i].physics;
                fStream << applicants[i].physics << endl;

                cout << "Enter maths grade: ";
                cin >> applicants[i].maths;
                fStream << applicants[i].maths << endl;

                cout << "Enter Russian language grade: ";
                cin >> applicants[i].RussianLanguage;
                fStream << applicants[i].RussianLanguage << endl;

                cout << "Enter English grade: ";
                cin >> applicants[i].English;
                fStream << applicants[i].English << endl;

                int sum = 0;
                sum += applicants[i].RussianLanguage + applicants[i].maths + applicants[i].physics + applicants[i].English;
                averageMark = static_cast<float>(sum) / 4.0;
                cout << "Student average mark: " << averageMark << endl;
                avg += averageMark;
            }

            studentAverageMark = avg / numberApplicants;
            //fStream << "University average mark: " << averageMark << endl;
            cout << "University average mark: " << studentAverageMark << endl;

        }

        if (count == 2)
        {
            while (!fStream.eof())
            {
                cout << endl << fStream.rdbuf();
            }
        }
    }
    fStream.close();
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь поймете, что к чему (над оптимальностью можете поработать):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct Student {
    double ball = 0;
};

int main()
{
    Student students[3];
    students[0].ball = 10;
    students[1].ball = 20;
    students[2].ball = 30;
    int averBall = 15;
    std::vector<Student> vecStudents;
    std::copy_if(std::begin(students), std::end(students),  std::back_inserter(vecStudents), [averBall](auto& elem){ return elem.ball > averBall;});
    std::sort(std::begin(vecStudents), std::end(vecStudents), [](auto& elem1, auto& elem2){ return elem1.ball > elem2.ball;});
    for (auto iter = std::begin(vecStudents); iter != std::end(vecStudents); ++iter)
    {
        std:: cout << iter->ball << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```